# Customizing the Windows Workflow Foundation like CryEngine Flowgraph

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, flowchart, workflow-foundation-4.5

I am beginning a new project that is designed to run a set of tasks based on certain criteria (File exists, timer, etc.).  I am interested in utilizing the Windows Workflow Foundation's flowchart functionality to achieve this goal, however I do not feel like it provides enough control.

I would like to be able to create an Activity that has not only multiple outputs, but accepts input visually.  The "Properties" grid is great for developers, but not necessarily end users.

In essence, I'm looking to implement something similar to a dumbed down CryEngine FlowGraph editor in C#.

Is this possible using/extending WF4.5 or should I spend heaps of time working on a custom WPF solution?  Are there any projects that will provide a similar visual designer out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of spending heaps of time working on a custom WPF solution, why don't you take a look at the available diagramming control libraries for WPF? WWF is not primarily meant to be customizable with each and every aspect, generic diagramming control libraries are, however.

Comment: My main reason for looking at a WF solution lies in the fact that the hydrating/dehydrating of workflows and the ability to run said workflows, all out of the box.  I've looked at the [Mindfusion](http://www.mindfusion.eu/wpfdiagram.html) solution and it seems to do exactly what I want visually, but I'd have to write the workflow execution logic myself.